# Create a PDF Reader( Python) with tab to translate + vocab storage

Tags: python, pdf

I search for a way to code/manipulate a PDF Reader to a extension that does the following:

1. Tab a word in the Text.
2. Translate the Word in a preferred language.
3. Underline the selected word in the text and Print the Translation on the right/left side of the row.

Is there any Reader out there that already do the Job, or, a open source python pdf code that can be manipulated that way?

I'm trying to get familiar with tools such as Word Mining to handle that, but, the biggest challenge will be to indicate the right row-coordinates for Printing the word, or, get access to a tab-to-translate function, isn't it?

I'm very new to coding and maybe it's a little ambitious but I always  use a (mobile) pdf reader Android/ios, I wish that function to be embedded.

Thx

Comment: For your first question you might get an answer for on stackexchange Software Recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

If the remaind distance from you and your goal is coding, just learning by doing, not that difficult to have some rough prototype. you will see more pictures during this process.

If all you know is daily using calculators like computers and smartphones, i suggest you install python, read some build-in .py files, then ask yourself if this is something you would like to conquer, ask a gain what if you are gonna have to create several files like this and organize these files together, would you have any fun at all?

Then ask again, how about do the whole thing all over again in order to create a smooth light weight android / os app, plus the frame constructors of mobile devices.

Any exciting?

if my intention is mobile apps, python wont be my first choice.

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer. I've already installed python and did some code, working with Self-teaching books and online tutorials. Sure, the process starts with rudiments, as you mentioned. The mobile App is a more a final goal, down a long road. I would be happy just get in the neighborhood of it, independent of the plattform or surface.